# I changed Joomla FTP password.... access denied

Tags: joomla, permissions, ftp

So, I changed my FTP password from my hosting panel.
And I've no idea what the old password was.
And now my website displays "Access denied." on every page.
It's a Joomla website.

Thank you for your help !

Edit: When I try to login on the admnistrator page, here is what I get :

Warning: include_once(/home/clients/6a0b43a5add26c536570d4cb7062e046/web/libraries/fof/config/provider.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/clients/6a0b43a5add26c536570d4cb7062e046/web/libraries/fof/autoloader/fof.php on line 87

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/clients/6a0b43a5add26c536570d4cb7062e046/web/libraries/fof/config/provider.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php5.6/lib/php') in /home/clients/6a0b43a5add26c536570d4cb7062e046/web/libraries/fof/autoloader/fof.php on line 87

Fatal error: Class 'FOFConfigProvider' not found in /home/clients/6a0b43a5add26c536570d4cb7062e046/web/libraries/fof/model/model.php on line 570

Then I cant get back to the administrator page, it keeps saying that error message.

Stefan

Comment: This is probably a question for your host, not this place.

Comment: Check the permission of file configuration.php. If its not writable change the permission to 755 temporarily. Change $ftp_enable = '1'  to $ftp_enable = '0'. Again change the permission of configuration.php to 444 after making changes. Check if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may have unintentionally changed the credentials that Joomla uses to connect to its database.

You'll need to know the username and password that your hosting account uses to connect to the Joomla database. If you don't know what these are you'll be able to find the username in your cPanel and you should be able to reset the password.

Then using either an FTP client or your cPanel file manager,
- open the configuration.php file in the root of your site
- locate the lines that start with **public $user** and **public $password**
- as precaution first copy and save the vales on these two lines
- then change their values to what you noted above, eg

```
public $password = "my_database_password";
```

That should do it.

The name of your Joomla database is set in the same configuration file on the line **public $db**. I think it's unlikely that you could have unintentionally changed this, though you could double check if updating your username and password doesn't work.

Good luck!

Comment: I didn't change my database credentials... So I tried to reset them but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The FTP section you see at the Joomla! admin is for handling FTP jobs between your website and the server and it can't manage the server's FTP account.
In any case, you can bring your site back by disabling FTP like what it was before. Since you have no access to the website, you can do it via FTP or cPanel. Go to root folder of the Joomla! site and open configuration.php file. Then change the value of   `public $ftp_enable = '1';` to  `public $ftp_enable = '0';`. It'll disable it again and you'll be able to see the website again.